# How to know the website a program is downloading from

Tags: download

Okay so there is an a application that downloads certain files.
Now I want to know if there is any way of getting the direct urls of the file it is downloading.

So please can anyone tell me which app can do so or is there any other method.

I need the direct download like not the website.

Comment: Knowing your Operating System will help us.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for instance. This acts as a webproxy, and will show all  request made from any application, as long as it's configured tho use Fiddler as a proxy. For most applications this will work automatically, for others you may have to set a proxy manually.